# Why can't I find this DIV that I appended to the body with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code should say enough: http://jsfiddle.net/dimadima/fLCCK/3/

```
// Append and return a newly created `div` element
$el = $('<div id="#test"></div>').appendTo($('body'));

// Now, try to find it:

// Nothing
var attempt1 = $('#test');

// Also nothing
var attempt2 = $('body').find('#test');

// Also nothing
var attempt3 = $('div#test');

// Returns both the pre-existing and dynamically appended divs.
var attempt4 = $('div');
```

Don't understand why I can't retrieve this div as in any of the first 3 attempts. The 4th attempt sort of retrieves it, but not in satisfactory manner. I feel like I've done this successfully a million times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `#` sign is for referencing the div. When you define it you need to omit it:

```
$el = $('<div id="test"></div>').appendTo($('body'));
```

Comment: Did this the other day and it drove me nuts.

Comment: @Yatrix, yes, I felt like I was going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `#` when you want to call a object.

```
$el = $('<div id="test"></div>').appendTo('body');
var length_test = $('#test').length;
console.log(length_test);
//outputs 1
```